# Why can't I access the style element in Javascript? Firefox console error message says it's "Null"

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I use scss and my stylesheet is a minified sheet syle.min.css.
I'm trying to make the analog clock project and the style element would get the rotation variable and rotate the hands of the clock respectively.
The code:

```
    setInterval(setClock, 1000);

const hourHand = document.querySelector('[data-hour-hand]');
const minuteHand = document.querySelector('[data-minute-hand]');
const secondHand = document.querySelector('[data-second-hand]');
//get the current date
function setClock() {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    //gets the current seconds
    const secondsRatio = currentDate.getSeconds() / 60;
    //gets the current minutes plus the socnds so it can gradually glide around the clock
    const minutesRatio = (secondsRatio + currentDate.getMinutes()) / 60;
    //gets the current hours plus the socnds so it can gradually glide around the clock
    const hoursRatio = (minutesRatio + currentDate.getHours()) / 12;
    setRotation(secondHand, secondsRatio);
    setRotation(minuteHand, minutesRatio);
    

setRotation(hourHand, hoursRatio);
}

//rotates the hands clockwise
function setRotation(element, rotationRatio) {
    //this is gonna take what property we want to set this in css so the ratation variable times the 360  
    element.style.setProperty('--rotation',rotationRatio * 360);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `setInterval(setClock, 1000);` after declaring hour, minute and second hand constants?

Comment: Do some debugging. Make sure that your variable `hourHand` actually contains what you expect along the way. What you have provided as code in your question looks fine. Does the HTML element hold the proper attribute that you are selecting by? Are you leaving out any structure in your code by any chance? Are the const variables out of scope?

Comment: i tried calling the `setInterva(setClock, 1000)` after the declaration didn't work any different.

Comment: Just wondering, you tagged the question `sass` but said you were using "scss". Did you mean "sass"? I want to edit this post, and want to fix it if you meant "sass".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the structure. As Martin said, I moved my script tag down and it stops it from returning that error message.